# Is there a Yasson/Json-b equivalent of JsonFormat.Feature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY

Tags: jsonb-api, yasson

I am converting a library from Jackson to json-b, but I cannot find the equivalent of JsonFormat.Feature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY. Does such a thing exist?

I got the following to work, but I hate to use Yasson internals to do so.

```
public static class ResultDeserializer implements JsonbDeserializer<List<Result>>
{

    public ResultDeserializer()
    {
    }

    @Override
    public List<Result> deserialize(JsonParser parser, DeserializationContext ctx, Type rtType)
    {
        // I have to use internals as there are no other ways to get this data
        if (((UserDeserializerParser) parser).getCurrentLevel().getLastEvent() == JsonParser.Event.START_ARRAY) {
            return ctx.deserialize(rtType, parser);
        } else
            return List.of(ctx.deserialize(Result.class, parser));
    }
}
```

Comment: hello, i am currently facing the exact same issue, were you able to find a solution? thanks in advance